# Error URL redirection

Tags: django, django-urls

urls.py:

```
url(r'^book/(?P<booktitle>[\w\._-]+)/(?P<bookeditor>[\w\._-]+)/(?P<bookpages>[\w\._-]+)/(?P<bookid>[\d\._-]+)/$', 'book.views.book', name="book"),
```

views.py:

```
def book(request, booktitle, bookeditor, bookpages, bookid, template_name="book.html"):

    book = get_object_or_404(book, pk=bookid)


    if booktitle != book.book_title :
        redirect_to = "/book/%s/%s/%s/%s/%i/" % ( booktitle, bookeditor, bookpages, bookid, )
        return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)

    return render_to_response(template_name, { 'book': book, },)
```

.

So the urls of each book are like this:

example.com/book/the-bible/gesu-crist/938/12/

I want that if there is an error in the url, then I get redirected to the real url by using book.id in the end of the url.

For example if I go to:

example.com/book/A-bible/gesu-crist/938/12/

then I will get redirected to:

example.com/book/the-bible/gesu-crist/938/12/

.

but if I go to wrong url I will get this error:

```
TypeError at /book/A-bible/gesu-crist/938/12/

%d format: a number is required, not unicode
```

.

If I use %s then I will get this error:

*The page isn't redirecting properly Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete. * This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.*

Why ?
What I have to do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All arguments passed to a view are strings. Shove it through `int()` before using it, or just use `%s` instead.

Comment: I have used %s but I get this error:

The page isn't redirecting properly     

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

    *   This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.

Comment: @xRobot: You're running into a redirect loop, which means that this statement `if booktitle != book.book_title` is always true... which would be because you're using `% ( booktitle, bookeditor, bookpages, bookid, )` instead of `(book.title, book.editor, ....)`

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, just replace the `%i` in

```
redirect_to = "/book/%s/%s/%s/%s/%i/" % ( booktitle, bookeditor, bookpages, bookid, )
```

With `%s`. Don't bother casting it to an integer.

Comment: I have used %s but I get this error: The page isn't redirecting properly Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete. * This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.